# django: needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: python, django

When saving a new entry into a Issue model for field cylinder, Django throws ValueError: "<IssueCylinder: anyone>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used. I understand this is because I need to save the first model before I can use the id of the new record in the second model, but I’m struggling with how to actually make it do this. I’ve looked at examples but I can’t really relate them to my models.
Your help will be nice for me. Here are that codes:

views:-

```
def issue(request):
    form=IssueForm()

    if request.method=='POST':
        form=IssueForm(data=request.POST,files=request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            confirm=form.save(commit=False)
            confirm.save()
            form.save_m2m()


            return redirect(cylinderListView)
    return render(request,'cylinderentry_form.html',{'form':form})
```

models:

```
class CylinderEntry(models.Model):
    substachoice=[
    ('Available','available'), 
    ('Unavailable','unavailable'),
    ('Issued','issued'), 
    
    ]
    
    cylinderId=models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    Availability=models.CharField(max_length=40,choices=substachoice,default="Available")
    EntryDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.cylinderId)

class IssueCylinder(models.Model):
    
    cylinder=models.ManyToManyField('CylinderEntry')
    userName=models.CharField(max_length=60,null=False)
    issueDate=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    
    
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        
        if not self.pk: 
            if self.cylinder.Availability=='Available':
                CylinderEntry.objects.filter(cylinderId=self.cylinder.cylinderId).update(Availability=('Issued'))
    
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        
        return str(self.userName)
```

form:

```
class IssueForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=IssueCylinder
        fields=['cylinder','userName','issueDate']

    cylinder= forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
                 queryset=CylinderEntry.objects.all(),
                widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
            )
    userName=forms.CharField()
    issueDate=forms.DateInput()
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't need a ForeignKey field instead of a Many2Many field? Your logic suggests that a Cylinder only has one Issue

Comment: I m little bit confuse with the working of ManyToMany relation, When do i required M2M relation and how to  add data to M2M relation.

Comment: M2M is when an cylinder can "have" multiple issues and an Issue can "have" multiple cylinders. If that's not the case you only need a ForeignKey Field.

Comment: I want to reissue a cylinder i.e. if cylinder1 issued to A user (after return)  , cylinder1 can be again issued to another user and so on. And also i want to make multiple cylinder issue i.e. for userA there can be more than one cylinder to be issued. So for this M2M relationship is not suitable?

Comment: It is ok then. Now I suggest you use a m2m_changed signal for your problem and you will lose that error.https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#m2m-changed

Comment: @EneP Thanks for the suggestion, I'll be back as soon as it works :)